# VM Kali Linux - nmap why is so slow?

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners

I was scanning an IP using this command: `nmap -sT -p- -Pn <Ip_Address>`, but is very slow scanning. To reach 100%, the command line said 3 hours remaining. Why is it so slow?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: @cremefraiche before i asked here , e google it , but i didnt find a solid infomation about this question and i am reading a book , this one:"The basics of Hacking and Penetration Testing " and in the book dont have nothink about that only have a exemple of using this command and how it is when reach 100 % , but is that normal taking so long time reaching 100% , why take that long?

Comment: Try reading the [manual](https://nmap.org/docs.html), or searching for questions on here before posting.

Comment: Is it just one IP address or many? Where is this IP? On the Internet or in your lab? We need to understand the context before we can help you.

Comment: If you like reading , this one is complete: https://nmap.org/book/cover/nns-cover.pdf (it has been written by nmap's author). It's down to packet level so it is not obsolete. Some new scan are not part of the book tho (-sY for instance)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bonsaiviking's answer is valid, but here are a few more points:

1. -sT scan realise a full TCP handshake, it takes significantly longer than a -sS (SYN Stealth Scan): Basically,

   - You send a **Syn**, Receive a
   - **Syn/Ack**(Opened) or a **RST** packet(Closed) or **nothing**(filtered)
   - If you get a **Syn/Ack**, you complete the connection with **Ack**: the connection is established.

With a Syn Stealth Scan, You do not establish a full connection, therefore do not have to complete it with an **Ack** packet and this is much faster.

2. You perform DNS resolution, if you scan multiple IPs or CIDR segment this would take long. you can skip this with **-n**
3. You do not use Timing Optimization: Refer to https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html ; Slow scans are annoying but reliable, fast scan can be noisy and unreliable: Nmap doesn't have time to check properly a port so gives up :(
4. You can check why the scan is taking forever by analyzing the process in debug or verbose mode: When verbose mode doesn't provide sufficient data for you, debugging is available to flood you with much more! As with the verbosity option (-v), debugging is enabled with a command-line flag (-d) and the debug level can be increased by specifying it multiple times. Alternatively, you can set a debug level by giving an argument to -d. For example, -d9 sets level nine. That is the highest effective level and will produce thousands of lines unless you run a very simple scan with very few ports and targets.

This is what I would suggest:

```
sudo nmap --min-hostgroup 100 -F -sS -n -T4 <Target_IP>
```

Answer (score 14):

Possibilities:

1. You are using a VM with a virtual NAT (Network Address Translation) network adapter. I have experienced profound slowdown under VirtualBox, for instance, when using NAT instead of a bridged network adapter.
2. You are scanning something that isn't there. The `-Pn` option means "don't bother trying to find out if anything is listening at this address, just start port scanning it." If the target is not actually there, you'll waste a lot of time sending packets into nowhere.
3. Your network (or your connection to the target) is slow. What is the latency to the target as measured by `nmap -sn` or `ping`? How far away is the target? What kind of network speed do you have? Any of these can impact total scan times.
4. You are performing a lot of work. The `-p-` option means to scan 65535 TCP ports. Depending on network conditions and host behavior, this can be a significant amount of traffic.

Comment: ,hi . I only want scan 1 ip , thats why i didnt use -Pn and the ip is from my laptop and is right next to me.i use ping command and send 7 packets he received 7 and the time =6012 ms.

Comment: @R.O.O.T that's 6 seconds per ping packet?? You have a massive networking problem.

Comment: @schroeder but i have a nice download speed ... i don have lag on internet , it could happend only on VM ?(  i am connected via wifi =$)

Comment: connecting to the internet and connecting to other machines on your network are 2 very different situations - we cannot help you with that

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be that you have not disabled DNS resolution and nmap is then "sometimes" trying to resolve the IP.
From (nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) -n (No DNS resolution) Tells Nmap to never do reverse DNS resolution on the active IP addresses it finds. Since DNS can be slow even with Nmap's built-in parallel stub resolver, this option can slash scanning times. The option describes that it is set to "sometimes" lookup - even on IP addr. only host.

Comment: WElcome to S.E. can, you expand this awnser with sources? or with reasining on why this would sow down the NMAP process? (this helps to get a better awnser ;) )